# Rails treats Ajax requests with format "json" as "text/html"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Versions

Ruby: 2.4.1

Rails: 5.2.3

jQuery: 3.4.1

### Problem

A request is sent from a page through Ajax which has `json` as a format but a Rails server thinks this request has a format `text/html`.

As a result, it generates `ActionView::MissingTemplate`.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template likes/json, application/json with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}
```

### My code

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :likes, only: %i(create destroy)
```

controller

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    item = Item.find(like_params[:item_id])
    like = Like.new(user: current_user, item: item)

    if like.save
      count = Like.where(item: item).count

      render :json, { count: count, like_id: like.id }
    else
      render :json, {}
    end
  end
```

view(slim)

```
.like-btn
  a href='#'
  .count = @like_count


javascript:
  $('.like-btn a').click( e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
      url: '#{likes_path(item_id: @item.id)}',
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      success: (data) => {
        $('.like-btn .count').text(data.count)
      }
    })
  })
```

### What I did

- ruby

  - try `respond_to`
  - try `render :plain, some_json, content_type: 'application/json`
- javascript

  - try `$.post`
  - set `contentType`, `type`, `data`

request object

```
# inside LikesController#create

(byebug) request.headers.to_h["CONTENT_TYPE"]
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
(byebug) request.format.to_s
"text/html"
```

---

## Update

I tried `#{likes_path(item_id: @item.id)}.json` and `'likes?item_id=#{@item.id}` but they didn't work and generated the same error.

Here is the request object. It doesn't have `json` in the url and the format is recognized as `text/html` even though the url in javascript has `json`.

```
# inside LikesController#create

byebug) request.url
"http://localhost:3001/likes?item_id=4"
(byebug) request.format
#<Mime::Type:0x007feea72326a0 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=-2254575977737173308>
```

---

## Update2

I tried `#{likes_path(item_id: @item.id, format: :json)` which generated `likes.json/item_id=4`, but the same error was generated.

```
# inside LikesController#create

(byebug) request.url
"http://localhost:3001/likes?item_id=6210"
(byebug) request.format.to_s
"text/html"
```

## Update3

I had an error in the `success` attribute in `$.ajax` and after removing that error, the Rails server started to recognizing the format as `application/json` but an error was still generated.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template likes/json, application/json with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending `.json` to the URL

```
url: "#{likes_path(item_id: @item.id, format: :json)}"
```

Also, in your controller, try this

```
def create
  item = Item.find(like_params[:item_id])
  like = Like.new(user: current_user, item: item)
  count = nil

  if like.save
    count = Like.where(item: item).count
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      if count
        render json: { count: count, like_id: like.id }
      else
        render json: {}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It should work!

Comment: Thank you for a comment, Rajdeep. I tried `#{likes_path(item_id: @item.id)}.json` and `'likes?item_id=#{@item.id}` but it didn't work and generated the same error.  

Here is the request object. It doesn't have `json` in the url and the format is recognized as `text/html`.

```
# inside LikesController#create

byebug) request.url
"http://localhost:3001/likes?item_id=4"
(byebug) request.format
#<Mime::Type:0x007feea72326a0 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=-2254575977737173308>
```

Comment: @masa_ekohe I just edited my answer, please give it a try

Comment: Thank you for a quick follow up, I tried and updated the original comment.

Comment: @masa_ekohe Just edited my answer, I guess you had a syntax issue with `render :json`, it should be `render json: {}` and not `render :json, {}`, try my edited approach combined with the first approach

Comment: You are right. Now it is behaving correctly. Thank you Rajdeep!